# PostGIS query failing due to escape string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, npgsql

I have this Postgres/PostGIS query:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(((E'-96.6864379495382')::float8) ((E'32.792527154088')::float8))', 4326),3081)
WHERE id=((10793455)::int4)
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "')::float8) ((E'"
LINE 2: ...sform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(((E'-96.6864379495382')::float8...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "')::float8) ((E'"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 94
```

I'm scratching my head because PostGIS doesn't have a problem with escaped data ([for example](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromEWKB.html)), and the query was generated from npgsql based on this parameterized query:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:longitude :latitude)', 4326),3081)
WHERE id=:id
```

I am running Postgres 9.1.5 and PostGIS 2.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error results from **unescaped single quotes** in the string. The standard way is to double them:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET    the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(
               'POINT(((E''-96.6864379495382'')::float8)
                     ((E''32.792527154088'')::float8))', 4326),3081)
WHERE  id=((10793455)::int4)
```

This fixes the string literal, but you have more errors.
Like @Paul hinted in a comment, [`ST_GeomFromText()`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) expects the [**geometry WKT `POINT(0 0)`**](http://postgis.org/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#RefObject). The explicit cast to `float8` makes it look like you are trying to enter the Postgres function [`point()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE) (had me confused at first). Simplify to:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET    the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(
                  $$POINT(96.6864379495382 32.792527154088)$$, 4326), 3081)
WHERE  id = 10793455
```

Note also, how I use [dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) in the second example to avoid having to escape single quotes altogether. As there aren't any single quotes left in your string literal after fixing the syntax, you might as well use single quotes again. Your parametrized query:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET    the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(
                  $$POINT(:longitude :latitude)$$::geometry, 4326), 3081)
WHERE  id = :id
```

You can add a cast to `geometry` to make it clear, like @Paul advises in his comment. But it works without explicit cast, too.

Comment: Thanks. You are right--I didn't even thing about the quoting. I was using pgAdmin III, and its color coding showed the numbers as different colors because the quoting was being undone before them, and I was lapsing back into my Visual Studio color coding thought paradigm where parameters have different colors.

Comment: Now another question: `$$POINT('-96.6864379495382' '32.792527154088')$$` doesn't work, but `$$POINT(-96.6864379495382 32.792527154088)$$` does. (With or without the comma between the parameters makes no difference.) Is this because PostGIS functions don't like quoted numbers?

Comment: POINT() isn't a function it's part of the text string representation of the point. You have to quote it too.  'POINT(1 1)'::geometry for

Comment: @PaulRamsey: Thanks for the clarification. [`point()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE) is *also* a function in basic PostgreSQL. The syntax Aren had (with cast to `float8`) looks like the function, which had me confused. I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ArenCambre: I had your syntax confused with the function `point()`. The geometry WKT `POINT(0 0)` requires different syntax. See my amended answer.

Comment: If I run that query (the first one in your answer), I get this error: `"POINT(((" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry`.

Comment: @ArenCambre: Obviously, it should be `POINT(` instead of `POINT(((`. Two to many. The first query in my answer only fixes the higher level syntax error stemming from unescaped single quotes. Doesn't make the query itself valid. The second query in my answer also fixes your lower level errors (incorrect syntax for `geometry` type). Follow the links to the manual I added for details.

Comment: Worth noting that you can avoid the clunky string syntax altogether if you use the ST_MakePoint function to construct the geometry.