# Npgsql parameterized query output incompatible with PostGIS

Tags: c#, postgresql, postgis, npgsql, prepared-statement

I have this parameterized query in an Npgsqlcommand:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:longitude :latitude)', 4326),3081)
WHERE id=:id
```

`:longutide` and `:latitude` are **double**, and `id` is **int**.

The query that is actually run against the DB looks like this:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(((E'-96.6864379495382')::float8) ((E'32.792527154088')::float8))', 4326),3081)
WHERE id=((10793455)::int4)
```

Thanks to help from Erwin Brandstetter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398904/postgis-query-failing-due-to-escape-string/12400182), it's apparent that the query needs to be simplified to work with PostGIS. He suggested this:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET    the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(
                  $$POINT(:longitude :latitude)$$::geometry, 4326), 3081)
WHERE  id = :id
```

I guess I could create this with a dynamic query, where I manually update the query every time I run it, but is there a way to make this work with a Npgsql parameterized query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert with `npgsql`, but I think your parameterized query could work like this:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET    the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(:mygeom, 4326), 3081)
WHERE  id = :id
```

And `mygeom` would hold this string:

```
POINT(96.6864379495382 32.792527154088)
```

.. pre-assembled from your other variables. Would result in a query like this:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET    the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(
             (E'POINT(96.6864379495382 32.792527154088)')::text, 4326),3081)
WHERE  id=((10793455)::int4)
```

Which should work.

---

If you have trouble assembling the string (like your comment demonstrates), there is a more elegant way. As per [hint from @Paul on my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398904/postgis-query-failing-due-to-escape-string/12400182#comment16715688_12400182) - PostGIS provides a dedicated function for the purpose:

```
ST_MakePoint(double precision x, double precision y)
```

[Details in the manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_MakePoint.html). With this, we finally arrive at:

```
UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET    the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(
               ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude), 4326), 3081)
WHERE  id = :id
```

Note the comma. Will it finally work now?
<sup>If not, just beat it with a sledgehammer. Grml.</sup>

It does - with [`ST_SetSRID()`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_SetSRID.html) now instead of `ST_GeomFromText()`. See comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still adds the types and escaping: `UPDATE raw.geocoding
SET the_geom = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(((E'-96.8569734692574 32.6630535721779')::varchar))', 4326),3081)
WHERE id=((12490336)::int4)`, which causes a different syntax error: `ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "32.6630535721779"`. My gut feeling is dynamically-constructed query.

Comment: @ArenCambre: This thing won't be killed, huh? I added another one.

Comment: Thanks. That worked with an exception: `ST_GeomFromText` becomes `ST_SetSRID`. `ST_GeomFromText` is unnecessary because `ST_MakePoint` makes a point, so there's no text to transform. Instead, I just need to set the SRID of the point. Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: @ArenCambre Makes sense. I amended the answer to a finally get to working parameterized query. Yay! :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used:

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(
                "select ST_Distance( ST_SetSRID(" +
                    "ST_MakePoint(@longitude, @latitude), 4326)," +
                    "(select geom from segments where segment_id= @id )," +
                    "true)",
                    m_DBConnection);
```

And it worked. Also, try with:

```
 NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(
                "select ST_AsText( ST_ClosestPoint( ST_GeomFromText('POINT(" +
                    longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat) + " " +
                    latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat) + ")', 4326)," +
                        "(select geom from segments where segment_id= @id )))",
                        m_DBConnection);
```

Thanks.