# Unable to INSERT between tables using ST_GeomFromText

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to insert point geometry values and other data from one table to another table.

```
-- create tables
create table bh_tmp (bh_id integer, bh_name varchar
                   , easting decimal, northing decimal, ground_mod decimal);
create table bh (name varchar);
    SELECT AddGeometryColumn('bh', 'bh_geom', 27700, 'POINT',3);

-- popualte bh_tmp
insert into bh_tmp values 
(1,'C5',542945.0,180846.0,3.947),
(3,'B24',542850.0,180850.0,4.020),
(4,'B26',543020.0,180850.0,4.020);

-- populate bh from bh_tmp
insert into bh(name, bh_geom) SELECT 
    bh_name, 
    CONCAT($$ST_GeomFromText('POINT($$, Easting, ' ', Northing, ' '
         , Ground_mOD, $$)', 27700)$$);
FROM bh_tmp;
```

Gives this error:

> ```
> ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
> SQL state: XX000
> Hint: "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
> ```

I can't see anything wrong with the `ST_GeomFromText` string that I've specified. But I can populate table `bh` if I insert rows 'manually', e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO bh (name, bh_geom)
VALUES ('C5' ST_GeomFromText('POINT(542945.0 180846.0 3.947)', 27700));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because the output of the CONCAT function is text, and your bh_geom column is geometry, so you're trying to insert text into geometry. This will work:

```
INSERT INTO bh(name, bh_geom) SELECT 
    bh_name, 
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' 
        || easting|| ' ' 
        || Northing 
        || ' ' 
        || Ground_mOD 
        || ')', 27700)
FROM bh_tmp;
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there is a misplaced semicolon after `CONCAT(...)`**`;`**

And you can't concatenate the function name itself into the string:

```
INSERT INTO bh(name, bh_geom)
SELECT bh_name
     , ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || concat_ws(' ', easting, northing, ground_mod) || ')'
                     , 27700)
FROM   bh_tmp;
```

Or, since you have values already (not `text`), you could use `ST_MakePoint()` and `ST_SetSRID()`:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(easting, northing, ground_mod), 27700)
```

Should be faster.

- [Npgsql parameterized query output incompatible with PostGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429874/npgsql-parameterized-query-output-incompatible-with-postgis)

Comment: Yes, the [second method is much faster and lossless](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58630/1872)

Comment: @MikeT: Excellent link. But in this case, either method should be lossless, since [`decimal` (= `numeric`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) is not a floating point, but an arbitrary precision data type. Representation of decimal digits is exact and lossless.